# Loading issue in product listing page

Tags: magento-1.8, product, product-attribute

I have 77K products in magento admin and out of 77K products 60K products are visible on front.
The quantity of rest of the product is zero(0).

There is one attribute named "Model" whose type is dropdown.
This dropdown have 2585 options.

Issue: 
When I try to open product listing page its taking too much time to load products.

Is there any one who can guide me to decrease page load?

Comment: How are you using  "Model" attribute in listing page ?

Comment: This is configuration for that attribute: http://prntscr.com/c6vehj

Comment: Try to set `Use in Product Listing` to No. Also do re-index if required

Comment: ok it means that I have to set Use in Product Listing to NO for the attribute which I don't want to show on product listing page?